# KENDO UI 'Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function'

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a very weird thing going on. 
When the below 2 scripts are added on my view. I got the error

> '**Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function**'

on success block of ajax call.

```
Html.AppendScriptParts(string.Format("~/Administration/Scripts/kendo/{0}/kendo.data.min.js", kendoVersion));
Html.AppendScriptParts(string.Format("~/Administration/Scripts/kendo/{0}/kendo.web.min.js", kendoVersion));
```

this is my response from backend.

```
{"ExtraData":null,"Data":[{"Id":3,"TotalLicense":0,"TotalAvailableLicense":0,"TotalSoldLicense":0,"TotalLicenseAssignedToCustomer":0,"ProductSKU":"SLN-PP-001","ProductName":"Prepaid code - Full Stream License BCM 30 days","LicenseNumber":"BCQH EKDJ LP8E","Runtime":null,"ActivationStart":"01/01/0001","ActivationEnd":"01/01/0001","OwnerName":"Suman Kumar","OwnerEmail":"contact@devodee.com","ShortDescription":null,"OrderNumber":7,"ProductSeName":"prepaid-code-full-stream-license-bcm-30-days","SearchProductSKU":null,"SearchProductName":null,"SearchLicenseNumber":null,"SearchOwnerName":null,"SearchOwnerEmail":null,"SearchOrderNumber":0,"ShowProductSKUFront":false,"ShowProductNameFront":false,"ShowLicenseNumberFront":false,"ShowRuntimeFront":false,"ShowActivationStartFront":false,"ShowActivationEndFront":false,"ShowOwnerNameFront":false,"ShowOwnerEmailFront":false,"ShowShortDescriptionFront":false,"ShowOrderNumberFront":false,"ShowProductSKUBack":false,"ShowProductNameBack":false,"ShowLicenseNumberBack":false,"ShowRuntimeBack":false,"ShowActivationStartBack":false,"ShowActivationEndBack":false,"ShowOwnerNameBack":false,"ShowOwnerEmailBack":false,"ShowShortDescriptionBack":false,"ShowOrderNumberBack":false,"CustomProperties":{}},{"Id":4,"TotalLicense":0,"TotalAvailableLicense":0,"TotalSoldLicense":0,"TotalLicenseAssignedToCustomer":0,"ProductSKU":"SLN-PP-001","ProductName":"Prepaid code - Full Stream License BCM 30 days","LicenseNumber":"DW4W BBAJ TFQX","Runtime":null,"ActivationStart":"01/01/0001","ActivationEnd":"01/01/0001","OwnerName":"Suman Kumar","OwnerEmail":"contact@devodee.com","ShortDescription":null,"OrderNumber":8,"ProductSeName":"prepaid-code-full-stream-license-bcm-30-days","SearchProductSKU":null,"SearchProductName":null,"SearchLicenseNumber":null,"SearchOwnerName":null,"SearchOwnerEmail":null,"SearchOrderNumber":0,"ShowProductSKUFront":false,"ShowProductNameFront":false,"ShowLicenseNumberFront":false,"ShowRuntimeFront":false,"ShowActivationStartFront":false,"ShowActivationEndFront":false,"ShowOwnerNameFront":false,"ShowOwnerEmailFront":false,"ShowShortDescriptionFront":false,"ShowOrderNumberFront":false,"ShowProductSKUBack":false,"ShowProductNameBack":false,"ShowLicenseNumberBack":false,"ShowRuntimeBack":false,"ShowActivationStartBack":false,"ShowActivationEndBack":false,"ShowOwnerNameBack":false,"ShowOwnerEmailBack":false,"ShowShortDescriptionBack":false,"ShowOrderNumberBack":false,"CustomProperties":{}}],"Errors":null,"Total":2}
```

And when i remove the below JS,

```
//Html.AppendScriptParts(string.Format("~/Administration/Scripts/kendo/{0}/kendo.data.min.js", kendoVersion));
```

the error varnished. But both these JS has to be added in the view for some other functionality.

```
kendo.web.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function
at init.success (kendo.web.min.js:13)
at i (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
at Object.n.success (kendo.data.min.js:11)
at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
at k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
```

[image: error :: script line and code]

Can anyone please elaborate what is going wrong here, am I missing anything?

Comment: Kendo throws these kind of errors when there is something wrong with your widget configuration, in this case a grid. Usually a binding to a function that cannot be found. You need to include the html and any related js for your grid in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [e.slice is not a function error in ASP.NET MVC with Kendo UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996897/e-slice-is-not-a-function-error-in-asp-net-mvc-with-kendo-ui)

Comment: @RomanKoliada No the question you referred to is different as mine is not MVC version. And also as suggested i am returning a Array to the grid not an object(please see the my backend response above)

Comment: @RomanKoliada No the question you referred to is different as mine is not MVC version. And also as suggested i am returning a Array to the grid not an object(please see the my backend response above)

Comment: @NigelK Yes all needed JS has been added. But the issue here is when i add both the Kendo.data and Kendo.web JS. It works when only Kendo.web JS is alone added.

Answer (score 4):

I too was getting this error when I used `kendo.DataSource` without a widget to retrieve a single object (serialized as JSON) from the backend. My fix was to add a fake `slice()` function that returns a clone of the object itself:

```
            schema: {
                data: (response: any) => {
                    // Augment returned data with a slice() method used internally by Kendo DataSource 
                    // in the absence of "schema.model" to obtain a pristine copy of the object.
                    response.slice = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                    return response;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I add my grid datasource and ı using databound  bind my data and and my data not add the combobox.I am curious why like this. my Code             dataBound: function (e) {
                var equipmentData = e.sender.dataSource.data();
                equipmentData.slice = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(equipmentData));                       
                $.each(equipmentData, function (index, selectedEquipmentData) {                                 
                        var dataItem = e.sender.dataSource.at(index); }) },

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error with a `kendoAutoComplete` editor control when clearing the control. It didn't happen when first typing characters into the control because it didn't make a server request until there were at least two characters entered. The control used server filtering to retrieve data via a JSON request. The issue was that I was testing for a null or empty filter on the server and in that situation returned an empty JSON object.

The fix was to return an empty JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a query in the refresh function of my Kendo ViewModel that was asynchronous and then attempting to pass the value to the function call immediately after to a ListView. It was empty when it was passed due to the AJAX query still being run.

```
UserProfileNotesViewModel.prototype.initialize = function () {
                var _this = this;
                if (!this.isInitialized) {
                    this.container = $("#user-profile-note-container");
                    this.addModal = $("#user-profile-entry-note-modal");
                    this.infoViewModel = new InfoViewModel(this);
                    this.refresh().then(function () { return _this.isInitialized = true;  });
                    let datasource = this.infoViewModel.get("data");
                    $("#notes-listview").kendoListView({
                            dataSource: {
                                data: data,
                                pageSize: 21
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: (response) => {
                                    // Augment returned data with a slice() method used internally by Kendo DataSource 
                                    // in the absence of "schema.model" to obtain a pristine copy of the object.
                                    response.slice = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                                    return response;
                                }
                            },
                            template: kendo.template($("#note-search-template").html()),
                            pageable: true
                        });
                }
            };
```

Instead, I added the notes-listview function call to an always block at the end of the AJAX query. This caused the data to be populated when it was requested.

```
UserProfileNotesViewModel.prototype.refresh = function () {
                var _this = this;
                kendo.ui.progress(this.container, true);
                return $.ajax({
                    url: Ccf.Utility.serviceUrl + "User/GetUserNotes/" + _this.options.userId,
                    method: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        _this.infoViewModel.set("data", data);
                    })
                    .fail(function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        _this.infoViewModel.set("messages", Ccf.Utility.getAjaxMessages(data));
                    })
                    .always(function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        kendo.ui.progress(_this.container, false);
                        $("#notes-listview").kendoListView({
                            dataSource: {
                                data: data,
                                pageSize: 21
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: (response) => {
                                    // Augment returned data with a slice() method used internally by Kendo DataSource 
                                    // in the absence of "schema.model" to obtain a pristine copy of the object.
                                    response.slice = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                                    return response;
                                }
                            },
                            template: kendo.template($("#note-search-template").html()),
                            pageable: true
                        });
                        if (!_this.isInitialized) {
                            kendo.bind(_this.container, _this.infoViewModel);
                        }
                    });
            };
```